# Root element with header and detail rows

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml-namespaces, for-xml-path

I use a for xml select to produce an xml file.
I want to have two root nodes that contain some header tags and then detail rows that are a result from a query on a table.

Example:

```
<Root>
 <FileHeader>

  HEADER ROWS

 </FileHeader>
 <Jobs>
  <Message xmlns="url">
   <Header Destination="1" xmlns="url"/>
   <Body>
     <ListItem xmlns="url">

       DETAIL ROWS FROM SELECT 

     </ListItem>

   </Body>
  </Message>
 </Jobs>
</Root>
```

The query I am trying to produce this is this one:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('url')
SELECT(
SELECT   

 HEADER ROWS

FOR XML PATH('FileHeader'),
TYPE),
(SELECT  

         '1'     AS 'Message/Header/@Destination',
         'url'   AS 'Message/Header/@xmlns'

FOR XML PATH(''),
TYPE), 
(SELECT  

 DETAIL ROWS FROM SELECT 

FROM MY_TABLE
FOR XML PATH('Jobs'),ROOT('Body'),   
TYPE      )
FOR XML PATH ('Root')
```

MY_table and its data are irrelevant as all tags inside the final select are correct are validated against the xsd schema. 
The FileHeader and Header tags are populated with values given from variables, so no tables are used there.

I am missing something on the middle part of the query (the second select). With my way, I can't have the Header tag inside the Jobs/Body path.

What is more, I cannot fill in the with xmlns value. I even used the following as I found on some forums and still can't manage to produce a well formatted tag with the xmlns attribute.

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('url' as xmlns)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I do not get what your final XML should look like... The XML you provide does not have *he Header tag inside the Jobs/Body path*.  Please poste an example of the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to state first:

- It is not allowed to add the namespaces `xmlns` like any other attribute
- It is possible to add this default namespace with `WITH XMLNAMESPACES`. But - in cases of sub-queries - this namespace will be inserte repeatedly. This is not wrong yet annoying and it can blow up your XML and make it fairly hard to read...
- You can create a nested XML *ad-hoc* (inlined), or prepare it first and insert it to the final query. This allows you to add default namespace to a deeper level only.

It's not absolutely clear to me, what you are really looking for, but this might point you in the right direction:

```
DECLARE @HeaderData TABLE(SomeValue INT,SomeText VARCHAR(100));
DECLARE @DetailData TABLE(DetailsID INT,DetailText VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @HeaderData VALUES
 (100,'Value 100')
,(200,'Value 200');

INSERT INTO @DetailData VALUES
 (1,'Detail 1')
,(2,'Detail 2');

DECLARE @BodyWithNamespace XML;
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'SomeURL_for_Body_default_ns')
SELECT @BodyWithNamespace=
(
    SELECT *
    FROM @DetailData AS dd
    FOR XML PATH('DetailRow'),ROOT('ListItem'),TYPE
);

SELECT(
        SELECT *    
        FROM  @HeaderData AS hd
        FOR XML PATH('HeaderRow'),ROOT('FileHeader'),TYPE
      )
      ,
      (
        SELECT 1 AS [Header/@Destination]
              ,@BodyWithNamespace
        FOR XML PATH('Message'),ROOT('Jobs'),TYPE
      )
FOR XML PATH ('Root')
```

The result

```
<Root>
  <FileHeader>
    <HeaderRow>
      <SomeValue>100</SomeValue>
      <SomeText>Value 100</SomeText>
    </HeaderRow>
    <HeaderRow>
      <SomeValue>200</SomeValue>
      <SomeText>Value 200</SomeText>
    </HeaderRow>
  </FileHeader>
  <Jobs>
    <Message>
      <Header Destination="1" />
      <ListItem xmlns="SomeURL_for_Body_default_ns">
        <DetailRow>
          <DetailsID>1</DetailsID>
          <DetailText>Detail 1</DetailText>
        </DetailRow>
        <DetailRow>
          <DetailsID>2</DetailsID>
          <DetailText>Detail 2</DetailText>
        </DetailRow>
      </ListItem>
    </Message>
  </Jobs>
</Root>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. I hadn't thought of using an XML variable to make my life simpler. The xmlnamespace also is perfect. Thank you! (once  again!)

Comment: @NotApplicable, don't know... Please edit your question and add an example of the XML how it should look like, together with explanation, where the data is coming from (table, parameters, fix values...)

Comment: in your example I would like to add an xmlnamespace in the message tag. Other than that, the example you have made is perfect. The produced xml is exactly in the form I wanted it to be.

Comment: @NotApplicable, My XML does not have a `<Body>`-element... Do you need the `xmlns` at `<ListItem>` **and** at `<Message>`? The outer would suffice...

Comment: I followed your example and used variables to insert it to the final query with the required xmlns so I'm perfect now. I thought the outer would suffice but it is needed by the xsd schema. Thanks again!!!