Splitting one row of data into two when exporting a SQL result into HTML
I have a result set in SQL Server (simplified and with fewer rows):



Name
Last Sale
Delivery Details
Call Date
Details




Smith
2024-06-13
Parcels go to side dr
2024-08-19
Enquiry re stk


Smith
2024-06-13
Parcels go to side dr
2024-08-24
Will call back


Smith
2024-06-13
Parcels go to side dr
2024-09-01
Payment Denied


Johnson
2024-09-25
Ring doorbell
2024-09-26
Payment Denied


Johnson
2024-09-25
Ring doorbell
2024-09-30
Payment Denied


Johnson
2024-09-25
Ring doorbell
2024-10-02
Payment Denied


Johnson
2024-09-25
Ring doorbell
2024-10-04
Payment Denied


Johnson
2024-09-25
Ring doorbell
2024-10-15
Payment Denied



Currently, using this code:
set @xhtmlbody = 
(
    select 
    (
        select 
            Name, Community, LastSale, DelDetails, CallDate, Details 
        from #Results2 for xml path('row'),type, root('root')).query
        (
            '<html><head>
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            (: including embedded CSS styling :)
            <style>
            table <![CDATA[ {border-collapse: collapse;  width: 300px;} ]]>
            th <![CDATA[ {background-color: #4CAF50; color: white;} ]]>
            th, td <![CDATA[ { text-align: left; padding: 8px;} ]]>
            tr:nth-child(even) <![CDATA[ {background-color: #f2f2f2;} ]]>
            #green <![CDATA[ {background-color: #3366cc;} ]]>
  </style>
         </head>
         <body style="font-family:Arial;">
<table style="width:100%" border="1">
    
   <caption><h1>{sql:variable("@tableCaption")}</h1><h2>Account Activity</h2></caption>
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Last Sale</th>
        <th>Delivery Details</th>
        <th>Call Date</th>
        <th>Details</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   {
    for $row in /root/row
    return <tr>
            <td>{data($row/Name)}</td>
            <td>{data($row/LastSale)}</td>
            <td>{data($row/DelDetails)}</td>
            <td>{data($row/CallDate)}</td>
            <td>{data($row/Details)}</td>
           </tr>
}
</tbody></table>
</body></html>'
));

This produces the result as you would expect, namely repeating the first three columns and then with a different final two. What I would like is to have the following header info per customer, as in:



Name
Last Sale
Delivery Details




Smith
2024-06-13
Parcels go to side dr






Call Date
Details




2024-08-19
Enquiry re stk


2024-08-24
Will call back


2024-09-01
Payment Denied






Name
Last Sale
Delivery Details




Johnson
2024-09-25
Ring doorbell






Call Date
Details




2024-09-26
Payment Denied


2024-09-30
Payment Denied


2024-10-02
Payment Denied


2024-10-04
Payment Denied


2024-10-15
Payment Denied



How do I go about this? Is it even possible?
I'm a little out of my comfort zone here, so can't really figure out the next step. I have looked elsewhere for ways to resolve it, but I can't find anything that suits this case.
EDIT - I should add that this is to then generate an email using SQL server, so the splitting of the queries up seems to be impossible?

Have you considered 2 separate queries?

Why use SQL to construct HTML? Is this to send to sp_send_dbmail  or something? If another application is involved will likely be better for that to construct the HTML with SQL Server just sending the results to it

this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39947323/root-element-with-header-and-detail-rows

Please try the following solution.
It simulates grouping by finding unique person names via XQuery distinct-values() function.
The rest is leveraging XQuery FLWOR expressions to compose XHTML tables per person name on the fly.
Also, it is possible to compose XHTML with one single table just alternating thead and tbody sections.
SQL
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (Name VARCHAR(20), [LastSale] DATE,  [DeliveryDetails] VARCHAR(30),  [CallDate] DATE, Details VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO @tbl (Name, [LastSale], [DeliveryDetails], [CallDate], Details) VALUES
('Smith',   '2024-06-13', 'Parcels go to side dr', '2024-08-19', 'Enquiry re stk'),
('Smith',   '2024-06-13', 'Parcels go to side dr', '2024-08-24', 'Will call back'),
('Smith',   '2024-06-13', 'Parcels go to side dr', '2024-09-01', 'Payment Denied'),
('Johnson', '2024-09-25', 'Ring doorbell', '2024-09-26', 'Payment Denied'),
('Johnson', '2024-09-25', 'Ring doorbell', '2024-09-30', 'Payment Denied'),
('Johnson', '2024-09-25', 'Ring doorbell', '2024-10-02', 'Payment Denied'),
('Johnson', '2024-09-25', 'Ring doorbell', '2024-10-04', 'Payment Denied'),
('Johnson', '2024-09-25', 'Ring doorbell', '2024-10-15', 'Payment Denied')
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @xhtmlbody XML;

set @xhtmlbody = 
(
select 
    (
        SELECT Name, LastSale, [DeliveryDetails], CallDate, Details
        FROM @tbl 
        ORDER BY Name
        FOR xml path('row'),type, root('root')).query
        (
            '<html><head>
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            (: including embedded CSS styling :)
            <style>
                table <![CDATA[ {border-collapse: collapse;  width: 300px;} ]]>
                th <![CDATA[ {background-color: #4CAF50; color: white;} ]]>
                th, td <![CDATA[ { text-align: left; padding: 8px;} ]]>
                tr:nth-child(even) <![CDATA[ {background-color: #f2f2f2;} ]]>
                #green <![CDATA[ {background-color: #3366cc;} ]]>
            </style>
         </head>
         <body style="font-family:Arial;">
         {
            for $person in distinct-values(/root/row/Name)
            return 
            (<table style="width:100%" border="1">
            (:<caption><h1>{sql:variable("@tableCaption")}</h1><h2>Account Activity</h2></caption>:)
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Last Sale</th>
                <th>Delivery Details</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
           {
            for $row in /root/row[(Name/text())[1] eq $person][1]
            return <tr>
                    <td>{data($row/Name)}</td>
                    <td>{data($row/LastSale)}</td>
                    <td>{data($row/DeliveryDetails)}</td>
                   </tr>
            }
            </tbody></table>,
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Call Date</th>
                        <th>Details</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {
                    for $row in /root/row[(Name/text())[1] eq $person]
                    return <tr>
                        <td>{data($row/CallDate)}</td>
                        <td>{data($row/Details)}</td>
                    </tr>
                }
                </tbody>
            </table>)
}
</body></html>'
));

SELECT @xhtmlbody;

Output
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
                table  {border-collapse: collapse;  width: 300px;} 
                th  {background-color: #4CAF50; color: white;} 
                th, td  { text-align: left; padding: 8px;} 
                tr:nth-child(even)  {background-color: #f2f2f2;} 
                #green  {background-color: #3366cc;} 
            </style>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family:Arial;">
    <table style="width:100%" border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Last Sale</th>
          <th>Delivery Details</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Johnson</td>
          <td>2024-09-25</td>
          <td>Ring doorbell</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Call Date</th>
          <th>Details</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>2024-09-26</td>
          <td>Payment Denied</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2024-09-30</td>
          <td>Payment Denied</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2024-10-02</td>
          <td>Payment Denied</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2024-10-04</td>
          <td>Payment Denied</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2024-10-15</td>
          <td>Payment Denied</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table style="width:100%" border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Last Sale</th>
          <th>Delivery Details</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Smith</td>
          <td>2024-06-13</td>
          <td>Parcels go to side dr</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Call Date</th>
          <th>Details</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>2024-08-19</td>
          <td>Enquiry re stk</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2024-08-24</td>
          <td>Will call back</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2024-09-01</td>
          <td>Payment Denied</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>



This is perfect! The only thing I've adapted is to make the second, detail table be the same width as the header one, as in reality the data in the Details is actually much longer than my example. This is brilliant though, thank you so much. I was nearly there with what I had been trying to do, but you have pushed me over the line. Thank you so very much. I've set as the accepted answer.

The only thing I can't quite figure out do is how I can get a  or similar at the end of each detail and before the next customer's header section? No matter where I put it, it either does nothing or throws up an error in SQL.

You can add it as <br/>, i.e. self-closing tag.
